# html parsing - objective c cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

is their a library like htmlAgilityPack for the iPhone/Mac OSX programming language. I really need to parse some html.

Answer (score 1):

For the iPhone you can use hpple to parse html/xml. It's a wrapper around the XPathQuery library, so you can use XPath to parse the html.

[github link](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in libxml, which is very good and has an HTML parser, XPath, etc.